# How to change log path in log4j2 at execution time

Tags: java, slf4j, log4j2

Hi I am using slf4j over log4j2.
How do I change log path dynamically?

My log4j2.xml looks like

```
   <Properties>
        <Property name="home">/path/logs</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="default" fileName="${home}/error.log"
                     filePattern="...">
               .......

        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
```

Is there any way I can change the path where logs will be written at runtime?

I tried with having system property in the path and setting it in runtime but log4j2 does not consider the updated value. System properties approach-

```
<RollingFile name="default" fileName="${sys:home}/error.log"
                     filePattern="...">

(In java class: System.setProperty("home","/newPath"))
```

Does this require reconfiguration. I don't see any exposed service of slf4j to reconfigure.

Answer (score 0):

Use [DOMConfigurator.doConfigure()](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/DOMConfigurator.html), where the second parameter is `LogManager.getLoggerRepository()`. This way you can change not just logging path, but everything else too, including levels for specific loggers, for example.

I don't think you can reconfigure SLF4j implementation using "implementation-agnostic" way. When we switched our application from Log4j to Logback, we also changed the way configuration file is re-read in runtime. For Logback this uses `JoranConfigurator.doConfigure()`.

Comment: Which LogManager are you talking about? Neither "org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager" nor "org.apache.log4j.LogManager" has "getLoggerRepository" method. Please specify the package

Comment: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/LogManager.html#getLoggerRepository()

Comment: Oh, you use log4j2, missed that sneaky 2. Nevermind then.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution i got is using context variable.

```
MDC.put("logLocation","path/to/log")
```

In log4j2.xml

```
<RollingFile name="default" fileName="${ctx:logLocation}/error.log"
                 filePattern="...">
```

However the catch is , for each thread the context should have this variable(logLocation) set